# How to get the default session from a tf.estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying the high API `tf.estimator`, but I find it hardly to get the session to debug some inter-result such as global step.

```
cls = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=my_model,
    params={
        'feature_columns': fcs,
        'hidden_units': [10, 10],
        'n_classes': 3,
    })
```

The example from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/custom_estimators

I have try `sess = tf.get_default_session` and `with tf.Session() as sess`, but can't get the defut session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use `tf.Print` like:

```
...
global_step = tf.Print(global_step, [global_step], message='Value of global step")
...
```

You can replace global_step with any tensor you want printed. Then when you run the training it will print the values every time the tensor is evaluated.

Another, more complicated way is to export the model then load it back in using your own session (not the estimator api). Once you do this you can call `session.run` for any operation defined. You can get operations with `tf.get_operation_by_name` or `tf.get_tensor_by_name`. You can also feed whatever values you want as a input.

Comment: Thanks. Does the `tf.estimator` fully shield the low api. If so, I can understant the reason why it can only work in with the `tf.Iterator.make_one_shot_iterator()`

Comment: tf.Print is marked as deprecated. in order to use new tf.print, it seems we have to get the session of the estimator first?

Comment: me too, the new tf.print doesn't print out anything